# How to remove old version of gurobi in Windows

Tags: python, conda, gurobi

I am using gurobi with anaconda and python, and recently downloaded an updated version (7.5.2) to update the already installed 7.0.2 version that is on my computer.

I can find the conda command line prompts to remove the conda installed package, but cannot find any code anywhere to remove the 7.0.2 version from my computer so that it doesn't keep referencing 7.0.2 when I try to install new version via conda again.

If anyone can offer any advice it would be much appreciated! Interesting that there is nothing in the gurobi docs that states how to do this.

Comment: what is your python version?  python -V

Comment: Did you originally install Gurobi standalone or install it from conda?

Comment: I installed Gurobi with conda - and am currently running version 3.5 Python. I did note that the latest Gurobi is only compatible with other versions of Python so this will be an additional work on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

`conda list` to see what's in the environment, and how it was installed.

If gurobi was installed as a conda package then use `conda uninstall gurobi`, if using pip then use `pip uninstall gurobi`.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the following - however when I go for another conda install gurobi, it is pulling up version 7.0.2 as the version to be installed. I'm not sure how I can prevent this?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Hi Bill - I am running Windows 10

Comment: What form does the installation code for gurobi, for Windows, come in? Is it an .exe, or a windows .msi install file?